# Can't initialize C-array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

my YYY.h file is

```
 #define W 1 // i am
 #define B 2 // opponent
 #define F 3 // board margin
static int boardPos[12][12];
@interface YYY : NSObject 
{...}
-(id)init;
@end
```

and YYY.m is

```
#import "YYY.h"


@implementation YYY

-(id)init
{   
    if (self = [super init]) {

        // initializing Empty Board

        boardPos[12][12] = {
            {F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
            {F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F}
        };
...
```

I got error "Expected expression before { token in "boardPos[12][12] = {" string. If I write something before boardPos - it become local variable; So I cant initialize this C-array properly. I need boardPos be visible in class scope. I tried to put it in class declaration - same error.

Btw, I already rewrite it on NSArray objects but still interesting how to deal with C-arrays.

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should write this in .m file

```
static int boardPos[12][12] = {
        {F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F},
        {F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F}
    };
```

and remove static int boardPos[12][12]; in .h, remove boardPos[12][12] = {
... } in .m.

This will make boardPos visiable only in this .m file.

Answer (score 3):

the array initialization has to be done as part of a declaration, i.e.:

```
in b[12] = {...};
```

it's not possible within a dynamic assignment...